# AngularJS Custom Validation Directive Unit Testing : model value is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, unit-testing, ngdescribe

I have a directive that adds a validator on my inputs to be used by ng-messages :

```
angular.module('app.module.submodule').directive('dateFormatFr', function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: linkValidator
    };
});

function linkValidator(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
    ctrl.$validators.datefr = function (modelValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(modelValue instanceof Date)) {
// this check avoid errors on datepickers
            return modelValue.match('^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$');
        }
        return true;
    };
}
```

And I'm trying to unit test it (using ng-describe) :

```
ngDescribe({
    name: 'linkValidator',
    modules: 'app.module.submodule',
    inject: [],
    mocks: {},
    only: true,
    tests: function () {
        var $compile,
            $scope,
            form;

        beforeEach(inject(function (_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
            // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching (Angular docs)
            $compile = _$compile_;
            $scope = _$rootScope_;
            var tpl = angular.element(
                '<form name="form">' +
                '<input ng-model="model.date" name="dateField" date-format-fr />' +
                '</form>'
            );
            $scope.model = {
                date: null
            };
            $compile(tpl)($scope);
            form = $scope.form;
        }));
        it('should be valid when the field value is well formatted (DD/MM/AAAA)', function () {
            form.dateField.$setViewValue('01/01/2001');
            $scope.$digest();
            expect(form.dateField.$valid).toBe(true);
            expect($scope.model.date).toEqual('01/01/2001');
        });
        it('should be invalid when date is badly formatted', function () {
            form.dateField.$setViewValue('30/02/2001');
            $scope.$digest();
            expect(form.dateField.$valid).toBe(false);
            expect($scope.model.date).toBeUndefined();
        });
    }
});
```

But there are 2 problems (that may have the same cause ??) :

1. the first test fails because `$scope.model.date` is `undefined` (it should be updated with `'01/01/2001'` as it is a valid input). I noticed that the `$modelValue` from `form.dateField` is also undefined. I know that `$scope.model.date` is updated, because if it won't, it would be `null`. But why `undefined` ?
2. the second test fails because `$valid` stays `true` (it should be updated with `false` as it is invalid). Again, I ask : why ?

I tried to compare my code to [this post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15219717/to-test-a-custom-validation-angular-directive) but I don't see where is my error.

Please note that the directive is working well in my app forms (model is updating as expected and ng-messages work too), so I have no clue what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm working with Angular 1.4.7, if it helps..

**EDIT :**

Tried [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372729/setting-view-value-an-input-field-in-a-unit-test-of-an-angular-form-directive) with the same result. The `$modeValue` keeps being undefined whereas `$viewValue` and `$$rawModelValue` are updated with the correct String.

These are logs from my test :

```
console.log($scope.localModel); 
// {date:null} before digest 
// {date: undefined} after digest
console.log(form.dateField.$viewValue); 
// NaN before digest 
// '01/01/2001' after digest
console.log(form.dateField.$modelValue);
// NaN before digest 
// undefined after digest
console.log(form.dateField.$$rawModelValue); 
// undefined before digest 
// '01/01/2001' after digest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad : I passed a String instead of a RegExp...

I also replaced the return statement by this one :

```
return /^(((0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])\/(0[13578]|1[02])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)\/(0[13456789]|1[012])\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|((0[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])\/02\/((19|[2-9]\d)\d{2}))|(29\/02\/((1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)(0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|((16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$/.test(modelValue);
```

Found it was more effective to use the "test" method when checking only one entry.

Sorry for those who spent time on it.